# Correct method for verts/bevel topology in a game asset

Tags: modeling

Can someone please explain to me what would be the appropriate way to deal with a bevelled curve like this to get decent topology. This will eventually be an Unreal Engine asset but I am struggling to work out how the inner geometry of the curve should be joining to the outer edge of the shape if done properly so that smoothing and texturing works correctly down the line.

[image]

Should every vert on the outside of the curve be joined to the outer edge of the face Like in this image?

[image]

This seems like I am adding extra verts when they may not be neccessary.  It also seems to make no difference to these lines I am getting in the smoothing.  How do I deal with these weird smoothing areas?

[image]

Comment: Try to enable the auto smooth function in the mesh properties and adjust its value.

Comment: In addition to what @FFeller said, every real time 3d engine converts meshes into triangles. Some game engines have problems with displaying narrow triangles and they usually mess up ngons with indentations like yours. Personally I would try to redistribute those vertices on the bottom of the mesh to both sides and then merge some of them until they are evenly triangulated.

Comment: Thankyou both, very helpful and the autosmooth adjust sorted out the problem - @metaphor_set - am I ok to triangulate then if the final product is Unreal? My (probably wrong) understanding was that you should stick to quads - if I can use tri's as well in some places life would be so much simpler.  I have been trying to avoid using tri's and ngons so far.

Comment: You can use tris if you create a static asset, e.g. assets that aren't going to deform. By using tris in some areas, you can reduce the polycount of your objects quite a bit.